# "Кто там?" — ударение

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

Иногда слышу, как ударение делают на "там", и меня это очень удивляет. Для меня естественно делать ударение только на первое слово "кто". Оно же ключевое!

А вы как считаете?

Comment: Сейчас смотрел советский фильм и, к своей радости, услышал нормальный для себя вариант.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MQBxX1cyMlE

Answer (score 1):

Если (реагируя на стук) обращаются к тому, кто за дверью, то ударение на *обоих* слогах (для лучшей разборчивости по другую сторону двери), а если вопрос адресован третьему лицу в том же помещении, то ударение только на "кто".

Comment: Спасибо, интересно!